# How to compare XML files in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, compare

I know that there has been a lot of questions like this but I couldn't find a reply that would satisfy my needs. I have to write an application that will compare XML files: there will be 2 types of compare, first for 2 files, listing all the differences and second one for multiple XML files listing all the variations from averages.

I am looking for some kind of class, library or API that will help me finish this task. Can you suggest some solutions ?

And yet, I do not know if I should use DOM or Xpath. Any suggestions ?

**EDIT:**

Ok so I have been trying to accomplish this task with XmlDiff tool but this is quite problematic to solve this for multiple Xml files - I have no idea how can I use this XmlDiffDiagram to sort out the differences among for instance 50 Xml files.

Is it going to be better with LINQ ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Microsoft's [XML Diff and Patch API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx) should work nicely:

```
public void GenerateDiffGram(string originalFile, string finalFile,
                       XmlWriter diffGramWriter)
    {
        XmlDiff xmldiff = new XmlDiff(XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreChildOrder |
                                      XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreNamespaces |
                                      XmlDiffOptions.IgnorePrefixes);
        bool bIdentical = xmldiff.Compare(originalFile, finalFile, false, diffGramWriter);
        diffGramWriter.Close();
    }
```

If you need to, you can also use the Patch tool to compare the files and merge them:

```
public void PatchUp(string originalFile, string diffGramFile, string outputFile)
    {
        XmlDocument sourceDoc = new XmlDocument(new NameTable());
        sourceDoc.Load(originalFile);

        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(diffGramFile))
        {
            XmlPatch xmlPatch = new XmlPatch();
            xmlPatch.Patch(sourceDoc, reader);

            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(outputFile))
            {
                sourceDoc.Save(writer);
                writer.Close();
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok, so I have read some articles about it and some documentation but I think that this is a good solution for comparing 2 documents. What about comparing a lot of them and them summarizing (reporting) the differences ?

Comment: How do you plan on displaying that? Sounds like it will require quite a bit of work.

Comment: The task is to perform 1)two xml files comparison and 2) multiple files comparison. In 2) I have to display for example ranges of numbers (maybe average) and maybe variations from average (if for instance there will be the same value in all files except one) and variations in strings (I do not yet know how to do it). The user will be able to select XMLs from database to be compared.

Comment: -1: I'm sure this is a copy/pasted example, but could you please 1) use `XmlReader.Create` instead of `new XmlTextWriter`, and 2) put `using` blocks around those `XmlReader` instances. I will then upvote.

Comment: the download link on microsoft website doesn't work :(

Comment: @Niloofar I got it from NuGet

Comment: Worked well for me, but I did encounter bugs relating to comments (it ignored comments even though `XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreComments` wasn't specified)

Answer (score 7):

If you want just to compare XML's and you don't need to get what is difference, you can use [XNode.DeepEquals Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.deepequals.aspx):

```
var xmlTree1 = new XElement("Root",
    new XAttribute("Att1", 1),
    new XAttribute("Att2", 2),
    new XElement("Child1", 1),
    new XElement("Child2", "some content")
);
var xmlTree2 = new XElement("Root",
    new XAttribute("Att1", 1),
    new XAttribute("Att2", 2),
    new XElement("Child1", 1),
    new XElement("Child2", "some content")
);
Console.WriteLine(XNode.DeepEquals(xmlTree1, xmlTree2));
```

Comment: Sadly, XNode.DeepEquals does return false if the attribute order doesn't match, try exchanging the order of Att1 and Att2 for the second tree

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I would go with LINQ to XML.  You can find a good tutorial at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx

Comment: I have read some info about LINQ to XML and it's quite promising. Why nobody would vote this answer up ?

Comment: Is the XSD the same for both files?

Comment: Stupid question: what's XSD ?

Comment: is the schema of both xml files the same?  An XSD is a definition of the schema.  Put more simply: is the structure of each file the same?

Comment: If by the structure you mean order of elements, attributes etc. then it's not necessary but probably it's gonna be the same.

Comment: Not the orders, but the structures.  If the structures are going to be the same (same schema) then Jame's answer is better than my answer.  I had wrongly assumed that you were trying to compare data from 2 XML files of differing schema.