# Compare elements from 2 xml's

Tags: c#, xml

I am currently working on a project where I get a xml file from a client on daily basis, from which I need to read the data  and load it to the database. The way I have implemented this is, I generated a class from the xsd and read the xml file using StreamReader and deserialize the data and then loop through members and add them to the database.

Now, I got another requirement where I need to add a member to the database only if the member details have changed from the previous day's xml file. I can code it the same way and add a logic to search/compare the member details with previous day's xml file and add the member if any changes are found.

But this process is very inefficient, as I need to iterate through the previous day's xml for each member in new xml. Is there any efficient way to achieve this?

Please provide your suggestions. Thanks

Comment: you could load today's xml in a "staging" table in your database, and handle the comparison & update at the database level with a stored procedure.  Each day, empty out the "staging" table and load the new xml, then run your stored procedure.

Comment: checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096173/how-to-compare-xml-files-in-c

Comment: I already checked that link and the comparison output does not match the original xsd ..hence I will not be able to deserialize the result....https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to compare values not by previous xml file, but with DB within your insert/update command.

```
IF(/* Check whether value changed code*/) BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ...
END
```

This way you don't have to track previous xml files etc.

Comment: No, I cannot use the database logic, as the data from xml is spread across  different tables

Comment: The data being “spread across different tables” will not prevent you from using “database logic”.

Comment: Well, I had bad experiences with file logic before.. Like getting files late, getting same file accidentally, or getting 10 files at once after a system down on data provider side etc. Each of them is another case, where I suggest to rely your saved data for comparison. If you really need to compare files, I've been there too :) Please code it your own, since sometimes diff api will tell you a value and following few values are changed, but you see that new node is inserted and others are not changed etc.

Comment: @DourHighArch Yes it does not prevent me, but my concern is reading multiple times from any data source (xml or db) would be a performance hit...and more over we have data purging every weekend. So on every monday there will no data to compare aganist

Comment: I just found there is a LastModified and CreatedDateTime fields in the xml . I am planning to get more details about these fields from  the client..and if they are intented to work  properly..I can use these fields and compare with currentDateTime...and all members whose LastModified or CreatedDateTime is equal to currentDatetime will be loaded to database....This way i dont have to compare with any older data source

Comment: Hope you can use it. Maybe you can ask your client to provide only modified nodes to you.. The best code is the code you never wrote :)

Comment: @RamazanBinarbasi Yes I agree, I already put the request for just providing modified nodes :)..but didnt get any response yet...they seem to have designed their logic based on generating cumulative xml's... :)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a case where you can harness the power / resources of your database and let it do the comparison / update / insert.  Load your daily file into a staging table, and run a query or stored procedure which identifies which records need to be updated, rather than attempting to do this comparison from c#.

You mentioned in previous comments that this is not possible because the data is spread across different tables.  If the comparison against that data is too complex, then you can keep 2 days worth of data in your staging table -- with a datetime stamp to differentiate which record set is "today" and which is "yesterday".  Run a query to identify same versus different, and return the results back to c# where you can then continue with your logic that handles the data distribution / updates.