# XML comparison - returns correct results but fails due to formatting of XML

Tags: c#, xml

I am quite new to the world of C# programming and am doing some API testing. The problem is that when I compare what is in my API and what is in the database, the values are the same but the XML formatting is different. I have no idea where to go next.

Here is my code:

```
    public void ApplicationSettingListTest()
    {
        var ApplicationSettings = CashClientService.wsp_ApplicationSettings_GetAll().ToList();

        List<List<String>> applicationSettingsList = new List<List<string>>().ToList();

        foreach (wsp_ApplicationSettings_GetAllResult appSettings in ApplicationSettings) {

            List<String> appList = new List<string>();

            appList.Add(appSettings.Description.ToString());
            appList.Add(appSettings.FunctionalAreaName.ToString());
            appList.Add(appSettings.ApplicationSettingValue.ToString());

            applicationSettingsList.Add(appList);

        }

        List<List<string>> ApplicationSettingsQuery = ApplicationSettingsQuery =DbQueries.dbo.applicationSettings.getPartialApplicationSettings(con).ToList();

        String errorMessage = QATools.Report.Lists.FindDifferencesInTwoListsOfLists("Given list does not match the list in the database", "The list in the database does not match the given list", applicationSettingsList, ApplicationSettingsQuery);
        Assert.IsEmpty(errorMessage , errorMessage); 
    }
}
}
```

My applicationSettings Class:

```
    public class applicationSettings
{
    private static string getApplicationSettingsQuery = "SELECT [Description] , appt.[ApplicationSettingTypeName] ,fa.[FunctionalAreaName] ,[ApplicationSettingValue] FROM [dbo].[ApplicationSettings] apps inner join dbo.[ApplicationSettingType] appt on apps.[ApplicationSettingTypeID] = appt.[ApplicationSettingTypeID]  inner join dbo.functionalarea fa on fa.[FunctionalAreaID] = apps.[FunctionalAreaID]";
    private static string getPartialApplicationSettingsQuery = "SELECT [Description] ,fa.[FunctionalAreaName] ,[ApplicationSettingValue] FROM [dbo].[ApplicationSettings] apps inner join dbo.[ApplicationSettingType] appt on apps.[ApplicationSettingTypeID] = appt.[ApplicationSettingTypeID]  inner join dbo.functionalarea fa on fa.[FunctionalAreaID] = apps.[FunctionalAreaID]";

    public static List<List<string>> getApplicationSettings(string constr)
    {
        return SqlFunctions.ExecuteSQLReaderList(constr, getApplicationSettingsQuery, 100).Select(y => y.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList()).ToList();
    }

    public static List<List<string>> getPartialApplicationSettings(string constr)
    {
        return SqlFunctions.ExecuteSQLReaderList(constr, getPartialApplicationSettingsQuery, 100).Select(y => y.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList()).ToList();
    }
}
}
```

My method to find differences in list of lists:

```
public static string FindDifferencesInTwoListsOfLists(string errorMessage1, string errorMessage2, List<List<string>> tmpfirstList, List<List<string>> TMPsecondList)
    {

        string pat = @"\r\n\s*";
        Regex rgx = new Regex(pat);

        List<List<string>> firstList = tmpfirstList.Select(y => y.Select(x => rgx.Replace(x.ToString().Trim(), " ").ToLower()).ToList()).OrderBy(x => x.ElementAt(0)).ToList();
        List<List<string>> secondList = TMPsecondList.Select(y => y.Select(x => rgx.Replace(x.ToString().Trim(), " ").ToLower()).ToList()).OrderBy(x => x.ElementAt(0)).ToList();


        //ranorex.Report.Info(firstList.Count() + "," + secondList.Count());
        List<List<string>> distinctFirst = firstList.Where(a => !(secondList.Count(b => b.SequenceEqual(a)) == firstList.Count(c => c.SequenceEqual(a)))).ToList();
        List<List<string>> distinctSecond = secondList.Where(a => !(firstList.Count(b => b.SequenceEqual(a)) == secondList.Count(c => c.SequenceEqual(a)))).ToList();


        //List<List<string>> distinctSecond = secondList.Where(a => !(firstList.Any(b => b.All(d => d.Equals(a.ElementAt(b.IndexOf(d))))))).ToList();
        //List<List<string>> distinctFirst = firstList.Where(a => !(secondList.Any(b => b.All(d => d.Equals(a.ElementAt(b.IndexOf(d))))))).ToList();


        string logOutput = "";
        if (distinctFirst.Count != 0)
        {
            logOutput += errorMessage1 + "\r\n";
            foreach (List<string> innerList in distinctFirst)
            {
                foreach (string text in innerList)
                {
                    logOutput += text + "|";
                }
                logOutput += "\r\n";
            }
            //ranorex.Report.Failure(errorMessage1, logOutput);
        }

        if (distinctSecond.Count != 0)
        {
            if (logOutput != "")
            {
                logOutput += "\r\n\r\n\r\n";
            }
            logOutput += errorMessage2 + "\r\n";
            foreach (List<string> innerList in distinctSecond)
            {
                foreach (string text in innerList)
                {
                    logOutput += text + "|";
                }
                logOutput += "\r\n";
            }
            //ranorex.Report.Failure(errorMessage2, logOutput);
        }

        return logOutput;
    }
```

And finally here is the output:

```
     Given list does not match the list in the database
invoice collection auto schedule|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema">
            <string>00:31</string>
          </arrayofstring>|
portalclientsamlrespondersigningthumbprints|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema">
            <string/>
          </arrayofstring>|
portalrimiliasupportsamlrespondersigningthumbprints|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema">
            <string/>
          </arrayofstring>|
render bands auto schedule|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema">
            <string>00:01</string>
          </arrayofstring>|
xmlfieldaddcustomermapping|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema">
            <string>remdata1,remdata1,remdata1,profit centre,txt,false</string>
            <string>remdata2,remdata2,remdata2,line 2,txt,false</string>
            <string>remdata3,remdata3,remdata3,line 3,txt,false</string>
            <string>remdata4,remdata4,remdata4,line 4,txt,false</string>
            <string>remdata5,remdata5,remdata5,line 5,txt,false</string>
            <string>remdata6,remdata6,remdata6,line 6,txt,false</string>
            <string>remdata7,remdata7,remdata7,line 7,txt,false</string>
            <string>remdata8,remdata8,remdata8,line 8,txt,false</string>
          </arrayofstring>|
xmlfieldaddpascustomermapping|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema">
            <string>allocationreference1,allocationreference1,allocationreference1,pc,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationreference2,allocationreference2,allocationreference2,l2,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationreference3,allocationreference3,allocationreference3,l3,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationreference4,allocationreference4,allocationreference4,l4,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationreference5,allocationreference5,allocationreference5,l5,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationreference6,allocationreference6,allocationreference6,l6,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationreference7,allocationreference7,allocationreference7,l7,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationreference8,allocationreference8,allocationreference8,l8,txt,false</string>
          </arrayofstring>|
xmlfieldaddpasholdingmapping|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema">
            <string>allocationreference1,allocationreference1,allocationreference1,pc,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationreference2,allocationreference2,allocationreference2,l2,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationreference3,allocationreference3,allocationreference3,l3,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationreference4,allocationreference4,allocationreference4,l4,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationreference5,allocationreference5,allocationreference5,l5,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationreference6,allocationreference6,allocationreference6,l6,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationreference7,allocationreference7,allocationreference7,l7,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationreference8,allocationreference8,allocationreference8,l8,txt,false</string>
          </arrayofstring>|
xmlfieldextractmapping|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema">
            <string>remdata1,remdata1,remdata1,po number (assignment id),txt,true</string>
            <string>remdata2,remdata2,remdata2,item text,txt,true</string>
            <string>remdata3,remdata3,remdata3,billing document (ref key 1),txt,true</string>
            <string>remdata4,remdata4,remdata4,customer reference (ref key 2),txt,true</string>
            <string>remdata5,remdata5,remdata5,ship to account number,txt,true</string>
            <string>relatedtransactionreference,relatedtransactionreference,relatedtransactionreference,related transaction reference,txt,true</string>
            <string>customerreasoncode,customerreasoncode,customerreasoncode,customerreasoncode,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationinstructionrequest,allocationinstructionrequest,allocationinstructionrequest,allocationinstructionrequest,txt,false</string>
            <string>comments,comments,comments,comments,txt,false</string>
          </arrayofstring>|
xmlinvoicedetailscustomlabels|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema">
            <string>invdata1,invoice hyperlink,true,hyperlink</string>
            <string>invdata2,invoice data 2,false,text</string>
            <string>invdata3,invoice data 3,false,text</string>
            <string>invdata4,invoice data 4,false,text</string>
            <string>invdata5,invoice data 5,false,text</string>
            <string>invdata6,invoice data 6,false,text</string>
            <string>invdata7,invoice data 7,false,text</string>
            <string>invdata8,invoice data 8,false,text</string>
          </arrayofstring>|



The list in the database does not match the given list
invoice collection auto schedule|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema"> <string>00:31</string> </arrayofstring>|
portalclientsamlrespondersigningthumbprints|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema"> <string/> </arrayofstring>|
portalrimiliasupportsamlrespondersigningthumbprints|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema"> <string/> </arrayofstring>|
render bands auto schedule|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema"> <string>00:01</string> </arrayofstring>|
xmlfieldaddcustomermapping|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema"> <string>remdata1,remdata1,remdata1,profit centre,txt,false</string> <string>remdata2,remdata2,remdata2,line 2,txt,false</string> <string>remdata3,remdata3,remdata3,line 3,txt,false</string> <string>remdata4,remdata4,remdata4,line 4,txt,false</string> <string>remdata5,remdata5,remdata5,line 5,txt,false</string> <string>remdata6,remdata6,remdata6,line 6,txt,false</string> <string>remdata7,remdata7,remdata7,line 7,txt,false</string> <string>remdata8,remdata8,remdata8,line 8,txt,false</string> </arrayofstring>|
xmlfieldaddpascustomermapping|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema"> <string>allocationreference1,allocationreference1,allocationreference1,pc,txt,false</string> <string>allocationreference2,allocationreference2,allocationreference2,l2,txt,false</string> <string>allocationreference3,allocationreference3,allocationreference3,l3,txt,false</string> <string>allocationreference4,allocationreference4,allocationreference4,l4,txt,false</string> <string>allocationreference5,allocationreference5,allocationreference5,l5,txt,false</string> <string>allocationreference6,allocationreference6,allocationreference6,l6,txt,false</string> <string>allocationreference7,allocationreference7,allocationreference7,l7,txt,false</string> <string>allocationreference8,allocationreference8,allocationreference8,l8,txt,false</string> </arrayofstring>|
xmlfieldaddpasholdingmapping|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema"> <string>allocationreference1,allocationreference1,allocationreference1,pc,txt,false</string> <string>allocationreference2,allocationreference2,allocationreference2,l2,txt,false</string> <string>allocationreference3,allocationreference3,allocationreference3,l3,txt,false</string> <string>allocationreference4,allocationreference4,allocationreference4,l4,txt,false</string> <string>allocationreference5,allocationreference5,allocationreference5,l5,txt,false</string> <string>allocationreference6,allocationreference6,allocationreference6,l6,txt,false</string> <string>allocationreference7,allocationreference7,allocationreference7,l7,txt,false</string> <string>allocationreference8,allocationreference8,allocationreference8,l8,txt,false</string> </arrayofstring>|
xmlfieldextractmapping|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema"> <string>remdata1,remdata1,remdata1,po number (assignment id),txt,true</string> <string>remdata2,remdata2,remdata2,item text,txt,true</string> <string>remdata3,remdata3,remdata3,billing document (ref key 1),txt,true</string> <string>remdata4,remdata4,remdata4,customer reference (ref key 2),txt,true</string> <string>remdata5,remdata5,remdata5,ship to account number,txt,true</string> <string>relatedtransactionreference,relatedtransactionreference,relatedtransactionreference,related transaction reference,txt,true</string> <string>customerreasoncode,customerreasoncode,customerreasoncode,customerreasoncode,txt,false</string> <string>allocationinstructionrequest,allocationinstructionrequest,allocationinstructionrequest,allocationinstructionrequest,txt,false</string> <string>comments,comments,comments,comments,txt,false</string> </arrayofstring>|
xmlinvoicedetailscustomlabels|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema"> <string>invdata1,invoice hyperlink,true,hyperlink</string> <string>invdata2,invoice data 2,false,text</string> <string>invdata3,invoice data 3,false,text</string> <string>invdata4,invoice data 4,false,text</string> <string>invdata5,invoice data 5,false,text</string> <string>invdata6,invoice data 6,false,text</string> <string>invdata7,invoice data 7,false,text</string> <string>invdata8,invoice data 8,false,text</string> </arrayofstring>|

  Expected: <empty>
  But was:  "Given list does not match the list in the database
invoice collection auto schedule|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema">
            <string>00:31</string>
          </arrayofstring>|
portalclientsamlrespondersigningthumbprints|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema">
            <string/>
          </arrayofstring>|
portalrimiliasupportsamlrespondersigningthumbprints|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema">
            <string/>
          </arrayofstring>|
render bands auto schedule|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema">
            <string>00:01</string>
          </arrayofstring>|
xmlfieldaddcustomermapping|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema">
            <string>remdata1,remdata1,remdata1,profit centre,txt,false</string>
            <string>remdata2,remdata2,remdata2,line 2,txt,false</string>
            <string>remdata3,remdata3,remdata3,line 3,txt,false</string>
            <string>remdata4,remdata4,remdata4,line 4,txt,false</string>
            <string>remdata5,remdata5,remdata5,line 5,txt,false</string>
            <string>remdata6,remdata6,remdata6,line 6,txt,false</string>
            <string>remdata7,remdata7,remdata7,line 7,txt,false</string>
            <string>remdata8,remdata8,remdata8,line 8,txt,false</string>
          </arrayofstring>|
xmlfieldaddpascustomermapping|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema">
            <string>allocationreference1,allocationreference1,allocationreference1,pc,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationreference2,allocationreference2,allocationreference2,l2,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationreference3,allocationreference3,allocationreference3,l3,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationreference4,allocationreference4,allocationreference4,l4,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationreference5,allocationreference5,allocationreference5,l5,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationreference6,allocationreference6,allocationreference6,l6,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationreference7,allocationreference7,allocationreference7,l7,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationreference8,allocationreference8,allocationreference8,l8,txt,false</string>
          </arrayofstring>|
xmlfieldaddpasholdingmapping|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema">
            <string>allocationreference1,allocationreference1,allocationreference1,pc,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationreference2,allocationreference2,allocationreference2,l2,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationreference3,allocationreference3,allocationreference3,l3,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationreference4,allocationreference4,allocationreference4,l4,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationreference5,allocationreference5,allocationreference5,l5,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationreference6,allocationreference6,allocationreference6,l6,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationreference7,allocationreference7,allocationreference7,l7,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationreference8,allocationreference8,allocationreference8,l8,txt,false</string>
          </arrayofstring>|
xmlfieldextractmapping|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema">
            <string>remdata1,remdata1,remdata1,po number (assignment id),txt,true</string>
            <string>remdata2,remdata2,remdata2,item text,txt,true</string>
            <string>remdata3,remdata3,remdata3,billing document (ref key 1),txt,true</string>
            <string>remdata4,remdata4,remdata4,customer reference (ref key 2),txt,true</string>
            <string>remdata5,remdata5,remdata5,ship to account number,txt,true</string>
            <string>relatedtransactionreference,relatedtransactionreference,relatedtransactionreference,related transaction reference,txt,true</string>
            <string>customerreasoncode,customerreasoncode,customerreasoncode,customerreasoncode,txt,false</string>
            <string>allocationinstructionrequest,allocationinstructionrequest,allocationinstructionrequest,allocationinstructionrequest,txt,false</string>
            <string>comments,comments,comments,comments,txt,false</string>
          </arrayofstring>|
xmlinvoicedetailscustomlabels|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema">
            <string>invdata1,invoice hyperlink,true,hyperlink</string>
            <string>invdata2,invoice data 2,false,text</string>
            <string>invdata3,invoice data 3,false,text</string>
            <string>invdata4,invoice data 4,false,text</string>
            <string>invdata5,invoice data 5,false,text</string>
            <string>invdata6,invoice data 6,false,text</string>
            <string>invdata7,invoice data 7,false,text</string>
            <string>invdata8,invoice data 8,false,text</string>
          </arrayofstring>|



The list in the database does not match the given list
invoice collection auto schedule|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema"> <string>00:31</string> </arrayofstring>|
portalclientsamlrespondersigningthumbprints|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema"> <string/> </arrayofstring>|
portalrimiliasupportsamlrespondersigningthumbprints|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema"> <string/> </arrayofstring>|
render bands auto schedule|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema"> <string>00:01</string> </arrayofstring>|
xmlfieldaddcustomermapping|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema"> <string>remdata1,remdata1,remdata1,profit centre,txt,false</string> <string>remdata2,remdata2,remdata2,line 2,txt,false</string> <string>remdata3,remdata3,remdata3,line 3,txt,false</string> <string>remdata4,remdata4,remdata4,line 4,txt,false</string> <string>remdata5,remdata5,remdata5,line 5,txt,false</string> <string>remdata6,remdata6,remdata6,line 6,txt,false</string> <string>remdata7,remdata7,remdata7,line 7,txt,false</string> <string>remdata8,remdata8,remdata8,line 8,txt,false</string> </arrayofstring>|
xmlfieldaddpascustomermapping|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema"> <string>allocationreference1,allocationreference1,allocationreference1,pc,txt,false</string> <string>allocationreference2,allocationreference2,allocationreference2,l2,txt,false</string> <string>allocationreference3,allocationreference3,allocationreference3,l3,txt,false</string> <string>allocationreference4,allocationreference4,allocationreference4,l4,txt,false</string> <string>allocationreference5,allocationreference5,allocationreference5,l5,txt,false</string> <string>allocationreference6,allocationreference6,allocationreference6,l6,txt,false</string> <string>allocationreference7,allocationreference7,allocationreference7,l7,txt,false</string> <string>allocationreference8,allocationreference8,allocationreference8,l8,txt,false</string> </arrayofstring>|
xmlfieldaddpasholdingmapping|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema"> <string>allocationreference1,allocationreference1,allocationreference1,pc,txt,false</string> <string>allocationreference2,allocationreference2,allocationreference2,l2,txt,false</string> <string>allocationreference3,allocationreference3,allocationreference3,l3,txt,false</string> <string>allocationreference4,allocationreference4,allocationreference4,l4,txt,false</string> <string>allocationreference5,allocationreference5,allocationreference5,l5,txt,false</string> <string>allocationreference6,allocationreference6,allocationreference6,l6,txt,false</string> <string>allocationreference7,allocationreference7,allocationreference7,l7,txt,false</string> <string>allocationreference8,allocationreference8,allocationreference8,l8,txt,false</string> </arrayofstring>|
xmlfieldextractmapping|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema"> <string>remdata1,remdata1,remdata1,po number (assignment id),txt,true</string> <string>remdata2,remdata2,remdata2,item text,txt,true</string> <string>remdata3,remdata3,remdata3,billing document (ref key 1),txt,true</string> <string>remdata4,remdata4,remdata4,customer reference (ref key 2),txt,true</string> <string>remdata5,remdata5,remdata5,ship to account number,txt,true</string> <string>relatedtransactionreference,relatedtransactionreference,relatedtransactionreference,related transaction reference,txt,true</string> <string>customerreasoncode,customerreasoncode,customerreasoncode,customerreasoncode,txt,false</string> <string>allocationinstructionrequest,allocationinstructionrequest,allocationinstructionrequest,allocationinstructionrequest,txt,false</string> <string>comments,comments,comments,comments,txt,false</string> </arrayofstring>|
xmlinvoicedetailscustomlabels|application administration|<arrayofstring xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema"> <string>invdata1,invoice hyperlink,true,hyperlink</string> <string>invdata2,invoice data 2,false,text</string> <string>invdata3,invoice data 3,false,text</string> <string>invdata4,invoice data 4,false,text</string> <string>invdata5,invoice data 5,false,text</string> <string>invdata6,invoice data 6,false,text</string> <string>invdata7,invoice data 7,false,text</string> <string>invdata8,invoice data 8,false,text</string> </arrayofstring>|
    "
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to share (possibly simplified) XML samples that differ, but should be considered to be identical?  A [mcve] that fully demonstrates the problem would be ideal, and maximize the chance we can find an answer.  Pre-existing questions include [How to compare XML files in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8096173) and/or [Check if XML element equals another XML element, ignoring empty values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27840908)